# How to create a test case for spring integration?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, spring-integration

I have an Ftp Configuration file like

```
 public class FtpConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sessionFactory.setHost("host");
        sessionFactory.setPort(21);
        sessionFactory.setUsername("ftpuser");
        sessionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromFtpChannel")
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGateway getFiles() {
        FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "get", "payload");
        gateway.setOptions(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.STREAM.getOption());
        gateway.setOutputChannelName("fileoutput");
        return gateway;
    }
}
```

And a Messaging Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface ReadFilesGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "fromFtpChannel", replyChannel = "fileoutput")
    InputStream readFiles(String directory);
}
```

The Messaging gateway is used to download files from the ftp server, to view the files as inputStream. A service FileService uses the gateway to read the files. How to write a possible testcase for the service, or the Messaging Gateway?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to test? 

This is a very simple integration application - it doesn't appear that there is anything to test.

The framework uses an embedded apache FTP server for integration tests; explore the test cases, such as [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ftp/outbound/FtpServerOutboundTests.java).

Comment: Also make sure that you re familiar with the Testing support in the Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html

Comment: I'm trying to test if the file is read or not